# Error event "loaded"

Tags: c#, xaml, unity-game-engine

I don`t understand this error occurs, though I have declared this method.
look at this code and error.

> 'WpfApplication5.MonoBehaviour' does not contain a definition for
>   'event_rotate' and no extension method 'event_rotate' accepting a
>   first argument of type  could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Code c# 1:

```
private void event_rotate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("asdasada");
}
```

Code c# 2:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
namespace WpfApplication5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : MonoBehaviour
```

Code xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication5.MonoBehaviour"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="event_rotate">
```

Comment: Your `x:Class` is set to `"WpfApplication5.MonoBehaviour"`, shouldn't that be rather `"WpfApplication5.Window2"`?

Comment: Try to make it visible to the XAML: `public void event_rotate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: if i set it receive this error "Partial declarations must not specify different base classes"

Comment: I tried this and does not work now

Answer (score 0):

the x:Class attribute has the wrong value. the x:Class attribute specifies the codebehind class that should be merged with the XAML code. you specified the MonoBehavior class in XAML. It should have been Window2. Window2 does contain the event declaration & that does not need to be public.

you can tell from the error message. after merging the files, the code exects the event_rotate method to be present in the codebehind. this method is declared in Window2 not in the specified MonoBehavior like x:Class sais.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity MonoBehaviour class is **not** a WPF Window base class and is therefore not appropriate to use as the base class for your Window2 class.  It could however be a property of that class (assuming you can instantiate it).

C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        // You must implement your own MyScriptClass that has MonoBehaviour as it's
        // base class and provide an appropriate constructor to use here, in the
        // Window2 constructor or some other appropriate location.
        private MonoBehaviour _monoBehaviour = new MyScriptClass();

        // Default constructor
        public Window2()
        {
            // Set up your _monoBehaviour here

            // Initialise the WPF Window GUI object
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Called by the WPF FrameworkElement.Loaded Event
        public void event_rotate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asdasada");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window2"
        Height="300" Width="300"
        Loaded="event_rotate"
        >
```

I'm not familiar with the Unity framework and don't know how you link it's GUI implementation with the XAML Window.  I'd assume that you will want to data bind an approriate `UserControl` container class to a public property that exposes the private `_monoBehaviour` implementation.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I have a question.For example,If i want to rotate a cube i should to create a class with name "mycuberotate" and initialize the object _monobehaviour=new mycuberotate?

Comment: @DiacoenscuCristian I'm not a game developer and can't answer questions about how to present your window content.  I've added the Unity3D tag to your question, so people with that expertise may pick it up.  My advice would be to consult the [Unity scripting tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting).